# Unsure of construction of tensor product from bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I've trouble understanding the definition of tensor products from the bases of the spaces which the operations is applied

Given two vector spaces $V$ and $ W $ over the same field, with bases $ B_V $ and $ B_W $ respectively, I understand that one can construct the tensor product of the two spaces, denoted $ V \otimes W $, and that the basis for this tensor product space is formed by the tensor products of the basis vectors of $ V $ and $ W $, like $ v_i \otimes w_j $ for $ v_i \in B_V $ and $ w_j \in B_W $.

However, I came across a description that talks about a function that maps a pair $ (v, w) $, where $ v \in B_V $ and $ w \in B_W $, to 1, and maps all other elements in the Cartesian product $ B_V \times B_W $ to 0, and this function is denoted as $ v \otimes w $. I am having trouble reconciling this description with my understanding of the tensor product, as I’ve always thought of $ v \otimes w $ as representing a specific element in the tensor product space, not a function.

Could someone clarify this function, how it relates to constructing tensor products, and how it should be properly interpreted? Additionally, any examples to illustrate this concept would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To use the specific case of $V = W = \mathbb R^3$, this is the natural correspondence of the dyadic $\hat{x}\hat{y}$ to the matrix \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
Also I think you mean $v \in B_V$, $w\in B_W$ in your third paragraph.

Comment: "I came across a description ..." - where exactly did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not really about tensors. We can do the same thing in the vector space $V$ alone. For every $a \in V$ there is an associated 'function' from $B_V$ to the ground field, such that its value on basis element $b_i$ is just the coefficient $\alpha_i$ in the (unique) decomposition $a = \sum \alpha_i b_i$ of $a$ with respect to this basis.